# How to recreate 2020 Google Maps icon's shape without SVG?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to recreate [Google Maps's icon (2020)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Google_Maps_icon_(2020).svg). The colorful background and the donut hole are easy enough: I just need some gradients and a mask.

Here's a snippet that shows my current efforts (and [a codepen](https://codepen.io/InSyncWithFoo/pen/dyQpqzq), if you want to play with it):

```css
:root {
  --1-3: calc(100% / 3);
  --2-3: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
  --sqrt-2: 1.4142135624;
  
  --hole-diameter: calc(100% / var(--sqrt-2) / 3);
  
  --red: #ea4335;
  --yellow: #fbbc04;
  --green: #34a853;
  --blue: #1a73e8;
  --azure: #4285f4;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 3em auto;
  width: 10em;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #c0392b, #8e44ad);
}

#icon {
  --mask: radial-gradient(
    circle at center,
    transparent calc(var(--hole-diameter) - 1px),
    #000 calc(var(--hole-diameter) + 1px)
  );
  
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      var(--red) var(--1-3),
      var(--yellow) var(--1-3) var(--2-3),
      var(--green) var(--2-3)
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      var(--blue) var(--1-3),
      var(--azure) var(--1-3) var(--2-3),
      var(--green) var(--2-3)
    ) calc(100% - 1px);
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
  rotate: -45deg;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="icon"></div>
</div>
```

However, I can't wrap my head around its peculiar shape. Is it possible to create such a shape with CSS only?

It should be obvious that I'm not looking for an SVG-based solution. I'm doing this as a pet project, so I just need something that works in at least one browser.

Comment: To enhance the shape, you can experiment with additional CSS properties like border-radius, transform, and box-shadow to fine-tune the curves and shadows.
keep in mind that css has limitation i hope this can be helpful

Comment: @ELMEHDIACHAHED I'm afraid that is not useful at all. If I could find such a combination I wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: @InSync In that case you should edit the title of your question to be explicit, e.g. "How can I recreate the 2020 Google Maps logo using only CSS box properties and built-in functions without any SVG?" - because otherwise everyone's going to say "use `background-image: url("data:{inline SVG logo}");`).

Comment: Honestly I prefer your sharp-corner version over Google Maps' official logo :)

Comment: That does look nice on its own might, indeed :) Edited the title to clarify the problem.

Comment: Can we use [CSS Shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_shapes)? Or the `path()` function? Technically it isn't SVG, but it does let you use SVG paths in CSS for things like masking and more.

Comment: @Dai That sounds good enough to be posted as an answer, though I prefer not having to resort to a path.

Comment: I'm working on something that almost-kinda works btw.

Comment: I was thinking that the "tip" of the logo and its general shape connected to the larger circle could be [modelled as a metaball-like goo](https://blobs.webflow.io/) - so [I made a blur-based metaball parameter editor on codepen](https://codepen.io/daiplusplus/pen/dyQOppm) and I get a kiiiinda similar shape with Opacity: 1, Blur: 204, Spread: 100, Contrast 50 - but this approach won't work unless there's a white background - nor can this be used as a `mask-image` - oh well...

Comment: That metaball trick looks so cool; I learn something new today. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @InSync I've posted my alternative solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximation with one element that should work in all the browsers:

```css
.logo {
  width: 200px; /* control the size */
  aspect-ratio: .7;
  background:
   linear-gradient(130deg,#0000 53%,#34a853 53.5%),
   conic-gradient(from 40deg at 36% 26%, #4285f4 25%,#fbbc04 0 50%,#ea4335 0 75%, #1a73e8 0);
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(#000 69%,#0000 71%) 
     bottom/10% 9% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(92% 173% at 100% 116%,#0000 98%,#000) 
     100% 97%/50% 18% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(92% 173% at 0%   116%,#0000 98%,#000) 
     0%   97%/50% 18% no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(from -35deg at 50% 90%,#000 70deg,#0000 0)
     bottom/100% 43% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(#0000 27%,#000 28% 70%,#0000 71%)
     top   /100% 70% no-repeat;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0 20px, #f9f9f9 0 40px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Google_Maps_icon_(2020).svg" width="200">
```

Comment: Looks a bit ruggy. Could you smooth it out?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best I could come up with, by abusing multiple `radial-gradient`, `-webkit-mask-image`, `-webkit-mask-image-composite` and, unfortunately: a sibling-element for the "*pointy-bit*" instead of being able to extend the original `#icon`, nor use an `::after` element (as the `::after` element will be clipped by the mask of its parent).

(I suppose this could be re-organized to make the circular part at the top use `::before` and the pointy-bit use `::after` and otherwise have `#icon` serve only as a container and bounds for its two psedoelement children, but that's an exercise left for the reader).

This is how it looks in Chrome. I haven't tested in any other browsers:

[image]

---

```css
:root {
    --1-3: calc(30%);
  --2-3: calc(70%);
    --sqrt-2: 1.41421356237;
    --inner-radius: calc(18.4%);

    --red: #ea4335;
    --yellow: #fbbc04;
    --green: #34a853;
    --blue: #1a73e8;
    --azure: #4285f4;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2em;
    margin: 1em;
}

#wrapper > div {
    border-radius: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #c0392b, #8e44ad);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper > div > h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#image > img {
  transform-origin: 50% 35%;
  /*transform: rotate(50deg);*/
}

#icon {
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-image:
        linear-gradient(
            180deg,
            var(--red) var(--1-3),
            var(--yellow) var(--1-3) var(--2-3),
            var(--green) var(--2-3)
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            180deg,
            var(--blue) var(--1-3),
            var(--azure) var(--1-3) var(--2-3),
            var(--green) var(--2-3)
        );
    
    background-position-x: 0, calc(100% - 1px);
    background-position-y: 0, 0;
    
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-mask-image:
    /* The radius of the circle at 100% is actually the corners of the bounding rect, not the perpendicular top+bottom/side edges, hence the weird numbers. */
    radial-gradient(
      circle at center,
      transparent 28.2%,
      black       calc(28.2% + 1px),
      black       70%,
      transparent calc(70.0% + 1px)
    );
    
    rotate: -50deg;
  
  z-index: 10;
}

#tip {
  aspect-ratio: 26 / 25;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #47A756;
  margin-top: -14.2%; /* this is relative to the #tip element's *width* btw. */
  z-index: 5;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      130deg,
      var(--yellow) 0% 25.5%,
      var(--green) 25.5%
    );
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image:
    radial-gradient( ellipse 127.3% 100% at -85.62% 60.5%, transparent 0%, transparent 100%, black 100% ),
    radial-gradient( ellipse 127.3% 100% at 185.62% 60.5%, transparent 0%, transparent 100%, black 100% ),
    linear-gradient( to bottom, black 55%, transparent 50% ),
    radial-gradient( ellipse 8.4% 8.8% at 50% 55%, black 100%, transparent 100% );

/* https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mask-composite/ */
  -webkit-mask-composite:
    source-in,
    source-in,
    source-over;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
  <div id="image">
    <h2>Google Maps Logo SVG</h2>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Google_Maps_icon_(2020).svg" alt="Google Maps icon"/>
    </div>
    
  <div id="attempt">
    <h2>Image-Mask Abuse</h2>
    <div id="icon"></div>
    <div id="tip"></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks *accept*able. I'm starting a bounty as soon as SO lets me, and if there's no better answer I'll mark this as accepted as well as giving it the bounty.

Comment: "*...I haven't tested in any other browsers*" - this is how it looks in Firefox (114.02/Ubuntu 23.04): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp5ID.png (and that screenshot is after I correct the apparent `margin-top` typo in the `#tip` rule-set)).

Comment: @DavidThomas lol